# I want to hide Action Bar while scrolling the webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

Basically i have BottomNavigationView activity in that there are 3 fragments (tab1,tab2,tab3) which contain 3 webviews, what i actually wanna to do is while scrolling down the webview my actionbar should hide, like`getSupportActionBar().hide();` i know already there are answers in the stack overflow for the same question, but i don't know what to do in my case, because i am a beginner in android development

here is my **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        />

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

**This is my first fragment** (*fragment_tab1*)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial.tab1">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress"
        android:progress="20"/>

</FrameLayout>


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</WebView>
```

This is my **java** code for *tab1*

```
package com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.polysocial;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


  /**
  * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.


  */

public class tab1 extends Fragment {



 public ProgressBar bar;
 public FrameLayout frameLayout;
public tab1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, null);



    frameLayout=(FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frame1);
    bar=(ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    bar.setMax(100);

    final WebView view=(WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    view.loadUrl("http://facebook.com");
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){


        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view1,int progress){

            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bar.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress==100){

 frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

 super.onProgressChanged(view1,progress);
        }
    });

    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    bar.setProgress(0);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: Use coordinator layout in your activity_main.xml

Comment: after that ?@randy

Comment: http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample idea of implementation.

```
 boolean isShowing;
//oncraete code is here
WebView mScrollView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
  mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            float mfloat = mScrollView.getScrollY();
            if (mfloat >= tToolbar.getHeight() && isShowing) {
                toolbarAnimateHide();
            } else if (mfloat == 0 && !isShowing) {
                toolbarAnimateShow(0);
            }
        }
    });

    private void toolbarAnimateShow(final int verticalOffset) {
    isShowing = true;
    //tToolbar is your view(any view)

    // add getSupportActionBar().hide() this code here to hide actionbar
    // remove below code  or comment
    tToolbar.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
            .setDuration(180)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    toolbarSetElevation(verticalOffset == 0 ? 0 : TOOLBAR_ELEVATION);
                }
            });

}

private void toolbarAnimateHide() {
    isShowing = false;

    // add getSupportActionBar().show() this code here to showactionbar
    // remove below code or comment

    //tToolbar is your view(any view)
    tToolbar.animate()
            .translationY(-tToolbar.getHeight())
            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
            .setDuration(180)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    toolbarSetElevation(0);
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: i don't have any scroll view

Comment: @Jaison_Joseph its object name and its web view not scroll view.

Comment: I have edited my answer and I have added comment for better understanding.

Comment: you are saying that , i can use this in my tab1.java (see my tab1 code)

Comment: In your case, You have write one interface which will notify activity to hide and show action bar.
You have to add scroll event in fragment and notify scroll event to activity using interface.

Here is a sample idea for fragment communication. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175820/transfer-data-from-fragment-a-fragment-b-fragment-c-when-user-click-back/43176242#43176242

Comment: so can you add your code in my code, in proper way, coz i am geting a lot of errors, and can you edit your answer as i sed

Comment: getViewTreeObserver() is not resolving